# Setting guide coordinates in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design

I want to specific the position of a guide manually, without dragging or using the mouse.

In Inkscape you can create a guide, then double or right-click to specify the X, Y coordinates of the guide. Here is what the dialog looks like.  I want some way to do something similar without dragging or using the mouse:

[image: editing a guide in Inkscape]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your guide by dragging it from the ruler (yeah, yeah...I know...). Select it by clicking on the guide, then enter your precise coordinates in the top bar (you'll only have to set x or y; the other coordinate won't matter).

[image]